# Merging 2 Flutter Apps with Hive in one single App

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I have the main application in Flutter using Hive as a database, and I would like to incorporate another single application that also has Hive as a database into this main app. I'm not experienced in Hive, so I don't really know what I need to do to merge both.

The code above is the `main.dart` from the main app:

```
    Hive
    ..init(document.path)
    ..registerAdapter(PostsAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox(appState);
```

This is from another `main.dart` one:

```
void main() async {
  //   hive initialization
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(TodoAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<Todo>(HiveBoxes.todo);
  runApp(TodoApp());
}
```

I've tried to run the app and got this error:

> HiveError: Box not found. Did you forget to call `Hive.openBox()`?

I do have a `boxes.dart` inside the folder of the second application with the following code:

```
class HiveBoxes {
  static String todo = 'todo_box';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive uses the concept of “boxes” for storing data in the database. A box is similar to a table on an `SQL database`, except that boxes lack a strict structure. This means boxes are `flexible` and can only handle simple relationships between data.

Before accessing the data stored inside a box, you must open it. This loads the entire `content` of the box from local storage into the memory so that any data present inside the box can be easily accessed.

The following example shows how to open a box named `peopleBox` and get the parameter name from it:

```
var box = await Hive.openBox('peopleBox');
String name = box.get('name');
```

Comment: Visit this https://blog.logrocket.com/handling-local-data-persistence-flutter-hive/ for more ,

Comment: Thanks for your time! I definitely need to take a deep look into Hive,  as soon I got a free time I'll handle it! Since I'm in rush, I was expecting an easy and direct solution. Thanks again!